# How to prevent new terms being added to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, terms

I've created some custom taxonomies using [register_taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Arguments), but I want to prevent new terms from being added. I noticed that there is a 'capabilities' argument available in register_taxonomy, is that what I should be using and if so, how would I use it?

Here's some of my code, I'm using a plugin I created to add the taxonomies (hence the public static function part). Is there an easy way to prevent new terms being created for my taxonomy?

Thanks

Osu

```
public static function register_directory_styles_taxonomy()
    {
        $labels = array(
            'name'                      => 'Music styles',
            'singular_name'             => 'Music style',
            'search_items'              => 'Search music styles',
            'all_items'                 => 'All music styles',
            'parent_item'               => 'Parent music style',
            'edit_item'                 => 'Edit music style',
            'update_item'               => 'Update music style',
            'add_new_item'              => 'Add new music style',
            'new_item_name'             => 'New music style',
            'choose_from_most_used'     => 'Choose from most used music styles'
        );

        $args = array(
            'hierarchical'  => true,
            'labels'        => $labels,
            'rewrite'       => false
            // 'show_ui'        => false
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'ibmstyles', 'ibmdirectory', $args );
    }
```

Comment: Why do you comment out `'show_ui' => false`?

Comment: You are on the right track with `capabilities`. You can take a additional look at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type, because there is a little bit mor information as on the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy. Besides that, this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16588/how-to-assign-multiple-roles-for-capabilities-array-withini-register-taxonomy-fu and this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/21411/how-do-you-add-custom-taxonomy-capabilities-exactly might help you. At the latter especially the link in the answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can block addition of new terms with a filter on `pre_insert_term`. The [source is helpful](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L2041) in working out what you can do.

```
add_action( 'pre_insert_term', function ( $term, $taxonomy )
{
    return ( 'yourtax' === $taxonomy )
        ? new WP_Error( 'term_addition_blocked', __( 'You cannot add terms to this taxonomy' ) )
        : $term;
}, 0, 2 );
```

Comment: you are just one of the best! learned something - again. Additional thought: combine that with `current_user_can()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can or `user_can()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/user_can for some `Role and Capability` http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities management.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thanks s_ha_dim and ialocin for your comments

Comment: Do I add the above code into my functions.php by itself?

Comment: @Pete Yes in functions.php of your current theme directory

Comment: How could this be edited to include an array of taxonomies?

Comment: This answer is really overkill and likely to confuse users. See this other answer to a similar (and older) question, it uses the `capabilities` argument of `register_taxonomy()`: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/144454/175

Comment: @jerclarke Agreed, users should use the default built in taxonomies capabilities.

Answer (score 4):

It would seem the easiest way to do this has been answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22173/read-only-taxonomy-user-can-assign-term-but-cant-create-or-edit-existing-terms/144454).

The solution was modifying the taxonomy's `capabilities` array:

```php
'capabilities' => array(
    'manage_terms' => '',
    'edit_terms' => '',
    'delete_terms' => '',
    'assign_terms' => 'edit_posts'
),
```

Comment: This is a MUCH better/cleaner solution than the accepted one.  Doing it this way removes the option from the interface entirely.